# meaning of "stiff"

Tags: meaning

In one of my posts ([How to ask the question "the difference is between which and what" in the idiomatic way?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241101/109190)) a nice answerer says

> you could ask (very formally) "What items are you differentiating?", but that seems a bit **stiff** ...

["stiff" on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stiff)

> behaving in a way that is formal and not relaxed
>
> severe and difficult
>
> There has been stiff opposition/resistance to the proposed tax increases.

That seems to convey that someone is not going to compromise, which might be not corresponding that answerer's opinion.

What does "stiff" mean in that context?

In other words (a Big Thank to @Jack O'Flaherty), a stiff writing style might

1. annoy audiences/reads
2. is not easy to understand
3. make audiences/reads uncomfortable, but not annoy them
4. the opposite of friendly but not annoy audiences/reads
5. others

Comment: stiff essentially means "too formal or rigid" in this context.

Comment: @Fermichem Thank you! So, it just means not interesting and has nothing to do with annoyance or lack of politeness, right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much,  I would say if a text is stiff it's too formal. It doesn't read smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

A body in rigor mortis is stiff, meaning rigid. So, we can call a corpse “a stiff”.

A living person who is similarly rigid in posture, attitude or thought can also be called “a stiff”, which is a bit of an insult: you’re so rigid you might as well be dead.

Such people also tend to have unnaturally formal writing and speech, so we call that “stiff” too: the words may be correct, but they’re not *alive*.

Answer (score 0):

[AHD "stiff"  4b](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stiff)

4.b. Lacking grace or easy charm; very formal: a stiff writing style.

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you. I updated my question, would you please take a loot at that?

Comment: Have you looked up the terms of the definition I gave? "grace", "charm"?

Comment: I [looked it up](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241311/109190), and still don't understand clearly. Suppose "grace" means "politeness, fair and honest", the opposite meaning would be" lack of politeness" for that context. So, ask someone "What items are you differentiating" reflect lack of politeness, is my understanding right?

Comment: For 'grace', how about this definition from a dictionary: Seemingly effortless beauty or charm of movement, form, or proportion. Where did you look it up to  get "fair and honest"?

Comment: I cited that from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grace), and I went through each definition in [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241311/109190)

Comment: I also looked it up on your dictionary, and found the explanation "Seemingly effortless beauty or charm of movement, form, or proportion", however, this piece only have me remember the picture of Rose in Titanic.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your quote was:

> You could ask, very formally, "what items are you differentiating?", but that seems a bit **stiff**.

#### "**stiff**" means overly formal and aristocratic.

Some other synonyms are shown below:

- stilted
- imposing
- hoity-toity
- snooty
- commanding
- imperial
- overly-dignified
- pretentious
- aloof
- formal
- stuck-up
- stilted
- overly-proper
- stately
- implacable
- indomitable
- unassailable
- steely
- aristocratic

[image: LIKE A SIR INTERNET INFOGRAPHIC]