# the usage of "habit"

Tags: word-usage

A post [present continuous for a temporary habit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/181461/109190) uses the word "habit" to describe how often a guy comes home.

> Since David began studying in the USA he hasn't **come back very often**

I am aware that "habit" means

> something that you do often and regularly, sometimes without knowing that you are doing it

source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/habit)

I have a feeling that the "habit" is a choice, consider the examples

> I always buy the same brand of toothpaste out of habit.

what brand of toothpaste is a choice, the guy could have chosen other brands, they don't have to choose a specific brand. This is the situation where the word "habit" would be used.

However, coming back not very often is not David's choice, he has do that because he is studying  in the USA.

In that context of "coming home", is it appropriate to use "habit"?

---

update for @Katy

**Note**: the asker uses the word "habit" in the title, not in the sentence above.

[image]

Comment: May I suggest that you quote the sentence in question, as the post at your link is quite long?

Comment: You're making up quite a lot of context for one sentence about David's travels (a sentence which doesn't even use the word 'habit'). It could very well be his choice, and there's nothing about coming home or not coming home that makes "habit" inappropriate.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. Is this your suggestion, "**come back very often**"?

Comment: @Katy I've updated my OP. What does "making up quite a lot of context" mean? too much, too big or something else?

Comment: No, I mean state your proposed use of "habit" in a sentence, rather than making users search for it in a very long post.

Comment: That referenced post's title needs a good edit. However it **is** 2 years old with no accepted answer so I think it has been forsaken

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I am not sure I understand I you meant. I will have been trying to do that :)  "I always buy the same brand of toothpaste out of habit", this is my quotation as well as my proposed use of "habit", is this your suggestion.

Comment: Then that sentence is unobjectionable. Why did it take a 10 or 15 line post to ask about it?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty The sentence of "toothpaste" is indeed unobjectionable, which is to demonstrate my proposed use of "habit". However, the use of "habit" in the quoted post is NOT in that way. In other word, I guess there should be a more appropriate expression that could be substituted for "habit" in the quoted post.

Comment: So, I would still have to follow a link to find the usage you are questioning?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty No need to to that. The inappropriate use of "habit" is right at the beginning of my OP, that is, uses the word "habit" to describe how often a guy comes home. I feel there should be a more appropriate expression that could be substituted for "habit" to describe how often a guy comes home, but I don't know what that expression is, that's why I posed my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a habit is an automatic, or even a reflexive response or action.  As in the buying of a favorite toothpaste. The use of the word 'habit' is a poor choice to describe the action 'not coming home often'.

Comment: Thank you for supporting my opinion. What is the more appropriate expression for the title of the post I quoted?

Comment: Merely answering the question. the word ' habit' is a poor choice to describe the action, OP must not of been able to formulate a better description. The others' comments are encouragement to construct shorter, less wordy, questions.